# Tensorflow processing with extremely big data

Tags: tensorflow

I have a large image file that I am trying to load and use with tensorflow (600000,20,64,64). I wanted to use feed_dict with a batch size but the array is too large to even load into a numpy array. Is there a method that I can use that will not require me to load the entire array in ?

Answer (score 2):

The "feed_dict" method is good only for small data. For large data, there is a `tfrecord` or `csv` formats which may be read in a separate thread by chunks which populate a tensorflow input data queue. More info on data reading from HDD is here - [how to read data in tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data).

There is also [a nice blog](http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/21/tfrecords-guide/) where it is shown how to prepare `tfrecords` from raw data.